# ESP8266 and mySQL

Tags: mysql, arduino, esp8266

To begin with, I set up my database which includes (an id (which is auto increment), username, email, and 2 more which are place0 and place1 (those two are boolean type)). Now my question is how can I connect an esp8266 directly to the database and update the booleans from 0 to 1 and back using a button for each one? Also, how can I read the boolean on the esp and turn an led for example? I need to make it update the values for a selected user not all of them....for example, I have users with id 1, 2, 3...i need to make the updates only on 1 if that one is selected...

Note that both the database and the esp8266 are in my house (on a local network)

Thanks very much

Nikolaos Konstantinou

NcCon

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is ESP8266 to Web Server(PHP/Python/NodeJS etc) to MySQL

Send the boolean values in the form of the HTTP Post method and handle the post method in Webserver then update the MYSQL table.

[check out this link](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-mysql-database-php/)

For some reason, if you want to avoid webserver you can try micro python upymysql module which helps to directly communicate the database from ESP board [uPyMySQL](https://github.com/dvrhax/uPyMySQL)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the link that you send but in that case, he adds a new row each time. I just want to update the value from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1

Comment: you need to use update SQL statements instead of the insert statements.